# List buckets that match a bucket label with gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I have my google cloud storage buckets labeled

I can't find anything in the docs on how to do a `gsutil ls` but only filter buckets with a specific label- is this possible?

Comment: Such a pain.  Every other gcp resource you interact with it via gcloud which has advanced filtering capabilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays is not possible to do what you want in one single step. You can do it in 3 steps:

1. getting all the buckets of your GCP project.
2. Get the labels of every bucket.
3. Do the `gsutil ls` of every bucket that accomplish your criteria.

This is my python 3 code that I did for you.

```py
import subprocess
out = subprocess.getoutput("gsutil ls")


for line in out.split('\n'):
    label = subprocess.getoutput("gsutil label get "+line)
    if "YOUR_LABEL" in str(label):
        gsout = subprocess.getoutput("gsutil ls "+line)
        print("Files in "+line+":\n")
        print(gsout)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just had a use case where I wanted to list all buckets with a specific label. The accepted answer using subprocess was noticeably slow for me. Here is my solution using the Python client library for Cloud Storage:

```
from google.cloud import storage


def list_buckets_by_label(label_key, label_value):
    # List out buckets in your default project
    client = storage.Client()
    buckets = client.list_buckets() # Iterator

    # Only return buckets where the label key/value match inputs
    output = list()
    for bucket in buckets:
        if bucket.labels.get(label_key) == label_value:
            output.append(bucket.name)
    return output
```

Answer (score 1):

A `bash` only solution:

```
function get_labeled_bucket {
  # list all of the buckets for the current project
  for b in $(gsutil ls); do
    # find the one with your label
    if gsutil label get "${b}" | grep -q '"key": "value"'; then
      # and return its name
      echo "${b}"
    fi
  done
}
```

The section `'"key": "value"'` is just a string, replace with your key and your value. Call the function with `LABELED_BUCKET=$(get_labeled_bucket)`

In my opinion, making a bash function return more than one value is more trouble than it is worth.  If you need to work with multiple buckets then I would replace the echo with the code that needs to run.

Answer (score 0):

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
for blob in client.list_blobs('bucketname', prefix='xjc/folder'):
  print(str(blob))
```

[image]